# How to install ffmpeg in a centos 7 vps

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos7

I just own a vps server & installed ffmpeg using the "FFMPEG Installer for CWP servers". But it comes with built-in developers packages. But i need some additional libraries enabled & compiled with ffmpeg.

Libraries i need to be enabled: gpl, libass, libfdk-aac, libfreetype, libfontconfig, libfribidi, libmp3lame, libopus, libtheora, libvorbis, libvpx, libx264, libx265, nonfree

Somebody please instruct me the commands that can download all the packages & compiles with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: Compile

libfdk-aac is considered to be incompatible with the GPL, and therefore nonfree and non-redistributable when used alongside `--enable-gpl`, so you should not find an already compiled build of `ffmpeg` supporting this encoder. **You will have to compile.**

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) for a step-by-step guide. It installs most of the stuff you listed, but not all of it, so you'll have to adapt it to suit your needs. That said, I'd personally skip libtheora and libvorbis: these have been superseded by libvpx and libopus.

Note that it will "install" the resulting executable files to `~/bin`. You can copy or move these to `/usr/local/bin` if you need them to be available in the the PATH for all users instead of just the user who compiled it.

## Option 2: Download

If you are willing to use the native FFmpeg AAC encoder instead of libfdk-aac then just [download this `ffmpeg` build](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and throw it in `/usr/local/bin`. This is the easiest option and it should support all or most of the external libraries you listed.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. But please give me the script that can run the installation as I'm completely new in this field.

Comment: is this codes helpful to run the install?<br>cd /usr/local/bin/
curl -O -L https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
tar -xvf ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
cd ffmpeg-git-64bit-static
yum -y install xz

Comment: @Totolhossain You don't need a script. Just copy and paste the commands as shown in the wiki link I provided. As for your commands you provided you don't need to use `yum`. Once you extract the archive it will create a directory that will contain the `ffmpeg` file. Move that file to `/usr/local/bin`. That's all you need to do.

Comment: it seems your instruction worked... But how can i install & enable :"libfdk-aac" "libfontconfig" & "nonfree" with the installation? IT must be configured & enabled with the ffmpeg. otherwise, my plugin will not work.

Comment: @Totolhossain As mentioned in the answer you must compile to use libfdk-aac. Try Option 1: Compile.